# Increasing Savagery: can you change the target?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

In MTG can [Increasing Savagery](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIncreasing%20Savagery%5d) flashback to a different target if the original target is removed from the battlefield?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you mean changing targets while the spell is on the stack?

Comment: Here's an example: I cast increasing savagery to put +5/5 counters on my elf warrior. My opponent then destroys that elf warrior on his turn, sending it to my graveyard. My question is, can I now cast increasing savagery from my graveyard for its flashback cost to put +10/10 counters on a different creature I have on the battlefield, say a war elephant or can it only be used on the elf warrior I first used it on?

Comment: Got it. Then Glorfindel has the right answer. Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the new flashbacked invocation of Increasing Savagery is an entirely different instance of the spell, and you may choose a new target, even if the original target is still on the battlefield.